# Azure functions .net 5.0 isolated ( extentions.json do not generated)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I try to run Azure functions basic Http trigger template and have an error that extensions.json file does not generated. Updating packages do not solve the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had repro’d and added steps below:

Created **function app** `.NET 5 (isolated)` with basic `“Http trigger”`.

Rebuild and run the function app and checked in a root folder `Extension.json` file has been generated.

[image]

Try to install the below package

For **.NET 5 (isolated)** - `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions` Package

For **.NET Core 3.0** - `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` package.

steps to know the exact [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375223/azure-functions-not-generating-extensions-json/64391246#64391246)